# How to run dart static analyze from terminal?

Tags: dart, static-analysis

I want to run analyzer from CI-script without actual build and of course without IDE. How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dartanalyzer`:

```
dartanalyzer --fatal-warnings *.dart
```

Comment: And for Flutter (the new Dart based mobile framework), the flutter command line tools supports the analyzer as well: `flutter analyze -h` will show you the options.